# Why Kurukshetra war took place?

Tags: mahabharata, kurukshetra

We all know that  greatest war was fought on the land of Kurukshetra in Mahabharata.
But I want to ask is why Kurukshetra war took place?  Was [Draupadi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draupadi)'s insult the only and main reason for it?

Comment: @Tezz will you tell me main/ specific reasons?

Answer (score 2):

> Was Draupadi's insult the only and main reason for it?

No. That is not the only reason. There were many reasons. Among them are:-

- The hatred of Kauravas towards Pandavas since childhood.
- The difference of opinion as to who should be the successor to the throne.
- The intolerance of Kauravas about the prosperity of Pandavas at Indrprastha.
- The deceptive dice game.
- Duryodhana's greed.
  .... And so on and so forth